# regex match everything but phrase

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Source

```
Challan Serial Number Status of matching with
                    OLTAS*
                </b></p>
            <p>1 1801.00 6910333 06-06-2014 18754 F
            </p>
            <p>2 1853.00 6910333 07-07-2014 22517 F
            </p>
            <p>3 1853.00 6910333 06-08-2014 21631 F
            </p>
            <p>4 1853.00 6910333 05-09-2014 13177 F
            </p>
            <p><b>PART A
```

I am trying to get all the data between `<p></p>`

`<\/p>.*<p>(.*)<\/p>.*<p>` this returns just one match

`^([^\b<p>]+)\b<p>` I am trying to create a word boundary but this is not returning any result

Comment: try this `(?s)<p\b[^>]*>\K(.*?)(?=<\/p>)`

Comment: One of the problems is that `\b` inside a character class means a backspace symbol. `<p>` inside the character class means `<`, `>`, `p`. And why using regex with HTML?

Comment: @stribizhev Because this is just part of the data and rest of the data is not properly tagged and creating issues for using HTMLDom

Comment: @Avinash this pattern is returning just one result how can I get all the data between `<p></p>`

Comment: I think this'll get you an array of data [Check This](https://eval.in/416745) @Shishant

Answer (score 0):

`/(?s)<p[^>]*>\K(.*?)(?=<\/p>)/`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the safest regex (it won't match `pre` tags) to match all separate `p` tags:

```
<p\b[^<]*>.*?<\/p>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN8yP9/1)

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FMOlS3):

```
$re = '/<p\b[^<]*>(.*?)<\/p>/s'; 
$str = "Challan Serial Number Status of matching with\n                    OLTAS*\n                </b></p>\n            <p>1 1801.00 6910333 06-06-2014 18754 F\n            </p>\n            <p>2 1853.00 6910333 07-07-2014 22517 F\n            </p>\n            <p>3 1853.00 6910333 06-08-2014 21631 F\n            </p>\n            <p>4 1853.00 6910333 05-09-2014 13177 F\n            </p>\n            <p><b>PART A"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
[0] => 1 1801.00 6910333 06-06-2014 18754 F
[1] => 2 1853.00 6910333 07-07-2014 22517 F       
[2] => 3 1853.00 6910333 06-08-2014 21631 F
[3] => 4 1853.00 6910333 05-09-2014 13177 F
```

Answer (score -1):

If You always sure in data format, You can use this:

```
(?<=<p>)[^</p>]*(?=</p>)
```

Because this regex not find strings contains `<,/,p,>` symbols;